# How to decrypt data in notepad++ if I forgot the pwd.

Tags: encryption, cryptography, notepad++, crypt

I got a problem in decrypting some information in Noptepad++. The situation is, that I have installed notepad++ and I used it to crypt some info. by using NppCrypt plugin. Everything was ok, I mean I used to decrypt and crypt several times using a pwd for that, nothing special. The problem occured when I reinstalled the program. I can not decrypt anymore those info by using the previous pwd. I was thinking that pwd also was introduced in generated code and somehow it takes from there. I need to decrypt those data, no matter how. I hope I was explicit about the problem and maybe someone can help me with that. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you chose the same algorithm as before?

Comment: I can not remember, and there are a lot of them. It will take a life to figure out which combination it is. I am wonder if it's possible to force it by breaking it.

Comment: It may take you a lifetime to break the password, but trying all available algorithms shouldn't take you more than 5 minutes.

Comment: nothing works, do you know a method to break it?